# Linux shell scripting - assigning tail value to a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tail

I'm setting up a shell script that reads the last line of a log file using:

```
tail -1 "/path/to/gdscript.log"
```

.. which is echo'ing the last line of the script just fine. The last line of the log dictates whether the process succeeded or failed, so I'm trying to run a quick echo as follows (this is the bit I'm failing at):

```
if [ (tail -1 "/path/to/gdscript.log")  == "Process Complete" ]; then
echo "Data Transfer OK"
else
echo "Data Transfer Failed"
exit 1
fi
```

.. but using the script above I'm getting:

```
./gdscript.sh: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `tail'
```

Can someone in the know show me how to format the IF gate above so that I can work off the last line of the log file? I'm new to shell scripting and would really appreciate the help.

Thanks,
Paul G

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the output of a command you need `$(cmd...)`. So I think you mean:

```
if [ "$(tail -1 '/path/to/gdscript.log')"  == "Process Complete" ]; then
...
```

Comment: That's not working - now getting "./gdscript.sh: line 12: [: too many arguments" for the line in question. Is there anything else I might try?

Comment: @PaulG - The parameter expansion needs to be quoted inside of `[`. The problem is that when the tail command returns nothing, you get `if [ == "foo" ]`. If you use `[[` instead, you don't have to worry about word splitting. I fixed this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should use:
`if [ $(tail -1 /path/to/gdscript.log)  == "Process Complete" ]; then`